# Does FFmpeg currently support AVIF?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, format, converters, avif

I installed FFmpeg using Chocolatey and confirmed that it is the latest version.
In order to convert the png file into an avif file, I gave the command as below in the cmd window of the administrator's authority.

```
ffmpeg -i input.png output.avif
```

Naturally, there are no characters in the file directory other than the ASCII code.
The following error codes were issued:

```
[NULL @ 00000211e91fd800] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output.avif'
output.avif: Invalid argument
```

And I tried googling a few times.

> https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7621 
> https://avif.io/blog/tutorials/ffmpeg/

etc. in other googling, there were no meaningful results.
Anyway, AVIF is supported on these sites.
I tried to write commands as they were required, but the command `ffmpeg -i image.png -c:v libaom-av1 -still-picture 1 image.avif` provided by the avif.io site did not work with the following error codes left below.

> Unrecognized option 'still-picture'.
> Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

AVIF is such a recent format that I don't even know if it's really supported by FFmpeg.
It is sure? What should I do? And if FFmpeg does not support AVIF, what can be a substitute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, AVIF muxing support was [added](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/84241e63cf2f3cc8f7d8a19e86b99f5af95d2a64) on 13th May 2022 to the master branch. So you need a git build since that date. Or wait for v5.1 which should be out in a few days.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think Chocolatey only supported the release version. The conversion was successful.

Comment: Any advice about how to add series of images into AV1? I tried this `ffmpeg -y -i 1.png -i 2.png -i 3.png -c:v libaom-av1 output.avif` but it shows that only one frame is added: `frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=0.0 Lsize=     272kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x`